# Require re-enter password before transaction

Tags: security, facebook-login

I've seen sites that you login with your facebook account, give a donation and it will save your CC information for future use.

The scary part is if your FB login is saved and say you walk away from your computer, someone can go to that with your login, donate to another organization with your credit card because it's saved.

An unlikely scenario, but still possible.  Is there a way to allow users to browse the website with the saved FB login, but require them to re-enter their password as the last step to complete their transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such functionality. It's called by docs [Re-Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/) and designed for cases exactly like this.

Citing [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/):

> In some applications, you may want to double-check the user's identity - perhaps before they make a purchase, or change some personal data. Re-authentication allows you to force the user to re-enter their Facebook password before they're passed back to your app.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.  I was thrown off looking for re-authorize instead of re-authenticate.